# Void pointer pointing to the same address

Tags: c++, python-3.x, memory-management, cython, void-pointers

## Problem

Void pointer to a cdef class is pointing to the same memory address without  forcing the the python reference counter.

## Description

I have a simple class that I want to store in a cpp vector by casting it to a void pointer. However, after printing the memory addresses the pointer is pointing to, it repeats after the second iteration, **unless** I force the reference counter to be increased by adding the new object to a list. Can somebody why the memory loops back without the reference counter enforcement?

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: extra_compile_args = -std=c++11
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libc.stdio cimport printf

cdef class Temp:
    cdef int a
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


def f():
    cdef vector[void *] vec
    cdef int i, n = 3
    cdef Temp tmp
    cdef list ids = []
    # cdef list classes  = [] # force reference counter?
    for i in range(n):
        tmp = Temp(1)
        # classes.append(tmp)
        vec.push_back(<void *> tmp)
        printf('%p ', <void *> tmp)
        ids.append(id(tmp))
    print(ids)
f()
```

Which outputs:

```
[140137023037824, 140137023037848, 140137023037824]
```

However if I force the reference counter by adding it to the classes list:

```
[140663518040448, 140663518040472, 140663518040496]
```

Comment: *"by casting it to a void pointer"* - don't! `void*` is pretty much always wrong

Comment: `cdef Temp tmp` declares a stack-allocated object, casting that to `void*` is extra wrong! And since you "replace" the object on each iteration, that is where your results come from (it reuses the same memory location)

Comment: Is there any other way to cast an cdef class to a pointer? Specifically my aim is to enforce thread safe parallelism with on different classes defined. However, in prange I can't use the python object directly unless I halt the gil directly. Casting it to a void pointer was the only other option I could scrounge from the net.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem, but if you want to use pointers, then you have to use pointers, e.g.: `cdef Temp* tmp = new Temp(1)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that only works with c++ classes and this isn't that. The main issue is that the current implementations I have are classes converted from python code into c++ structs (within cython no native c++ code). In order to utilize multithreading support either the classes have to be completely rewritten or I cast them to pointers I order to safely access. I think the problem I have is pretty niche due to the lack of examples online.

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  If you just want to release the GIL in some long-running method that you run on a background thread, Cython provides [a method](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#acquiring-and-releasing-the-gil) to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer became quite long, so there is a quick overview of the content:

1. Explanation of the observed behavior
2. Naive approach to avoid the problem
3. A more systematic and c++-typical solution
4. Illustrating problem for multi-threaded code in "nogil"-mode
5. Extending c++-typical solution for nogil-mode

**Explanation of the observed behavior**

The deal with Cython: as long as your variables are of type `object` or inherit from it (in your case `cdef Temp`) cython manages the reference counting for you. As soon as you cast it to `PyObject *` or any other pointer - the reference counting is your responsibility.

Obviously, the only reference to the created object is the variable `tmp`, as soon as you rebind it to the newly created `Temp`-object, the reference-counter of the old object becomes `0` and it is destroyed - the pointers in the vector becomes dangling. However, the same memory can be reused (it is quite probably) and thus you see always the same reused address.

**Naive solution**

How could you do the reference counting? For example (I use rather `PyObject *` than `void *`):

```
...
from cpython cimport PyObject,Py_XINCREF, Py_XDECREF    
...
def f():
    cdef vector[PyObject *] vec
    cdef int i, n = 3
    cdef Temp tmp
    cdef PyObject *tmp_ptr
    cdef list ids = []
    for i in range(n):
        tmp = Temp(1)
        tmp_ptr = <PyObject *> tmp
        Py_XINCREF(tmp_ptr)   # ensure it is not destroyed
        vec.push_back(tmp_ptr)
        printf('%p ', tmp_ptr)
        ids.append(id(tmp))

    #free memory:
    for i in range(n):
        Py_XDECREF(vec.at(i))
    print(ids)
```

Now all objects stay alive and "die" only after `Py_XDECREF` is called explicitly.

**C++-typical solution**

The above is not a very typical c++-way of doing things, I would rather introduce a wrapper which manages the reference counting automatically (not unlike `std::shared_ptr`):

```
...
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <Python.h>
    class PyObjectHolder{
    public:
        PyObject *ptr;
        PyObjectHolder():ptr(nullptr){}
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o):ptr(o){
           Py_XINCREF(ptr);
        }
        //rule of 3
        ~PyObjectHolder(){
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
        }
        PyObjectHolder(const PyObjectHolder &h):
            PyObjectHolder(h.ptr){}
        PyObjectHolder& operator=(const PyObjectHolder &other){
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
            ptr=other.ptr;
            Py_XINCREF(ptr);
            return *this;
        }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass PyObjectHolder:
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o)

...
def f():
    cdef vector[PyObjectHolder] vec
    cdef int i, n = 3
    cdef Temp tmp
    cdef PyObject *tmp_ptr
    cdef list ids = []
    for i in range(n):
        tmp = Temp(1)
        vec.push_back(PyObjectHolder(<PyObject *> tmp)) # vector::emplace_back is missing in Cython-wrappers
        printf('%p ', <PyObject *> tmp)
        ids.append(id(tmp))
   print(ids) 
   # PyObjectHolder automatically decreases ref-counter as soon 
   # vec is out of scope, no need to take additional care
```

Noteworthy things:

1. `PyObjectHolder` increases ref-counter as soon as it take possession of a `PyObject`-pointer and decreases it as soon as it releases the pointer.
2. Rule of three means we also have to take care in copy-constructor and assignment operator
3. I've omitted move-stuff for c++11, but you need to take care of it as well.

**Problems with nogil-mode**

There is however one very important thing: **You shouldn't release GIL** with the above implementation (i.e. import it as `PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o) nogil` but there are also problems when C++ copies the vectors and similar) - because otherwise `Py_XINCREF` and `Py_XDECREF` might not work correctly.

To illustrate that let's take a look at the following code, which releases gil and does some stupid calculations in parallel (the whole magic cell is in listings at the end of the answer):

```
%%cython --cplus -c=/openmp 
...
# importing as nogil - A BAD THING
cdef cppclass PyObjectHolder:
    PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o) nogil

# some functionality using a lot of incref/decref  
cdef int create_vectors(PyObject *o) nogil:
    cdef vector[PyObjectHolder] vec
    cdef int i
    for i in range(100):
        vec.push_back(PyObjectHolder(o))
    return vec.size()

# using PyObjectHolder without gil - A BAD THING
def run(object o):
    cdef PyObject *ptr=<PyObject*>o;
    cdef int i
    for i in prange(10, nogil=True):
        create_vectors(ptr)
```

And now:

```
import sys
a=[1000]*1000
print("Starts with", sys.getrefcount(a[0]))
# prints: Starts with 1002
run(a[0])
print("Ends with", sys.getrefcount(a[0]))
#prints: Ends with 1177
```

We got lucky, the program didn't crash (but could!). However due to race conditions, we ended up with memory leak - `a[0]` has reference count of `1177` but there are only 1000 references(+2 inside of `sys.getrefcount`) references alive, so this object will never be destroyed.

**Making `PyObjectHolder` thread-safe**

So what to do? The simplest solution is to use a mutex to protect the accesses to ref-counter(i.e. every time `Py_XINCREF` or `Py_XDECREF` is called). The downside of this approach is that it might slowdown the single core code considerable (see for example [this old article](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=214235) about an older try to replace  GIL by mutex-similar approach).

Here is a prototype:

```
%%cython --cplus -c=/openmp 
...
cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <Python.h>
    #include <mutex>

    std::mutex ref_mutex;

    class PyObjectHolder{
    public:
        PyObject *ptr;
        PyObjectHolder():ptr(nullptr){}
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o):ptr(o){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(ref_mutex);
            Py_XINCREF(ptr);
        }
        //rule of 3
        ~PyObjectHolder(){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(ref_mutex);
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
        }
        PyObjectHolder(const PyObjectHolder &h):
            PyObjectHolder(h.ptr){}
        PyObjectHolder& operator=(const PyObjectHolder &other){
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(ref_mutex);
                Py_XDECREF(ptr);
                ptr=other.ptr;
                Py_XINCREF(ptr);
            }
            return *this;
        }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass PyObjectHolder:
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o) nogil
    ...
```

And now, running the code snipped from above yields the expected/right behavior:

```
import sys
a=[1000]*1000
print("Starts with", sys.getrefcount(a[0]))
# prints: Starts with 1002
run(a[0])
print("Ends with", sys.getrefcount(a[0]))
#prints: Ends with 1002
```

However, as @DavidW has pointed out, using `std::mutex` works only for openmp-threads, but not threads created by the Python-interpreter.

Here is an example for which the mutex-solution will fail.

First, wrapping nogil-function as `def`-function:

```
%%cython --cplus -c=/openmp 
...
def single_create_vectors(object o):
    cdef PyObject *ptr=<PyObject *>o
    with nogil:
         create_vectors(ptr)
```

And now using `threading`-module to create

```
import sys
a=[1000]*10000  # some safety, so chances are high python will not crash 
print(sys.getrefcount(a[0]))  
#output: 10002  

from threading import Thread
threads = []
for i in range(100):
    t = Thread(target=single_create_vectors, args=(a[0],))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(sys.getrefcount(a[0]))
#output: 10015   but should be 10002!
```

An alternative to using `std::mutex` would be to use the Python-machinery, i.e.  [`PyGILState_STATE`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads), which would lead to code similar to

```
...
PyObjectHolderPy(PyObject *o):ptr(o){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();
    Py_XINCREF(ptr);
    PyGILState_Release(gstate);
}
...
```

This would also work for the `threading`-example above. However, `PyGILState_Ensure` has just too much overhead - for the example above it would be about 100 times slower than the mutex-solution. One more lightweight solution with Python-machinery would mean also much more hassle.

---

Listing complete thread-unsafe version:

```
%%cython --cplus -c=/openmp 

from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libc.stdio cimport printf
from cpython cimport PyObject  
from cython.parallel import prange

import sys

cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <Python.h>

    class PyObjectHolder{
    public:
        PyObject *ptr;
        PyObjectHolder():ptr(nullptr){}
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o):ptr(o){
            Py_XINCREF(ptr);
        }
        //rule of 3
        ~PyObjectHolder(){
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
        }
        PyObjectHolder(const PyObjectHolder &h):
            PyObjectHolder(h.ptr){}
        PyObjectHolder& operator=(const PyObjectHolder &other){
            {
                Py_XDECREF(ptr);
                ptr=other.ptr;
                Py_XINCREF(ptr);
            }
            return *this;
        }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass PyObjectHolder:
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o) nogil


cdef int create_vectors(PyObject *o) nogil:
    cdef vector[PyObjectHolder] vec
    cdef int i
    for i in range(100):
        vec.push_back(PyObjectHolder(o))
    return vec.size()

def run(object o):
    cdef PyObject *ptr=<PyObject*>o;
    cdef int i
    for i in prange(10, nogil=True):
        create_vectors(ptr)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! My skills in c/c++ are limited but this gives me some more insights on what is necessary for properly converting some of my other python code. This maybe a longshot, but do you recommend this approach for indexing into seperate classes using prange. I am looking for separate processes similar to how multiprocessing.Pool handles it. I can't really seem to find the correct search terms for this online / in the cython documentation.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler It is hard to say, without knowing exactly what you want to do. However, you should not use the above implementation if you plan to release GIL (i.e. prange) - see my last edit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last part? The ultimate goal is to create N classes where N is the number of threads such that I can use them in a threadsafe matter under prange. The objects will not be deleted under the prange only viewed / used.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler I have extended the solution to be thread-safe. If you know that ref-counters will not be changed, then you don't need the thread-safety - but sometimes it is not easy to make sure ref-counters aren't touched.

Comment: I really  need to brush up on my c++.. thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @ead if you're changing reference counts then I think you should be using the GIL and not c++ mutexes. I don't think it's valid to call Python API functions without the GIL

Comment: @DavidW you are probably right. I'm pretty sure mutex works as long as after releasing gil only open-mp threads are used (as in the example) - I saw some people doing it with success. I'm very much in doubt it works if threads are created with Python-machinery - that is the reason I also added  ` PyGILState_STATE`-bit which is just too much overhead to acquire/release for one single refcount-change.

Comment: @DavidW Actually it is probably just silly to have `std::vector` of `PyObject *` without gil anyway - you couldn't call almost any function with those `PyObject ` without acquiring gil. The only sensible approach would be to convert `PyObject`s into C-equivalents, put them into the vector, release gil and do the calculation in parallel.

Comment: @DavidW You was right, I have added an example (uses `threading`-module) for which mutex fails.

Comment: @ead I actually gave your code another look and made it work by defining the ptr in the cppclass definition, is this safe to do?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your objects end up at the same address is coincidence.  Your issue is that your python objects get destroyed when the last python reference to them goes away.  If you want to keep python objects alive, you will need to hold a reference to them somewhere.

In your case, since `tmp` is the only reference to the `Temp` object you create within your loop, every time you re-assign `tmp`, the object it was previously referencing gets destroyed.  That leaves blank space in memory that's conveniently exactly the right size to hold the `Temp` object that gets created in the next iteration of the loop, leading to the alternating pattern you see in your pointers.