# How to pass Cython extension types as arguments to Cython functions/methods?

Tags: cython

I’m writing a program using Cython. I have cdef classes (extension types) written in Cython. Some of the methods in my extension types use instances of other extension types (objects) as arguments. I would also like to be able to pass pointers to my extension types and store these pointers in a vector. When I try to compile, I get errors saying these extensions can’t be converted to Python objects. I can pass instances of basic types such as 3 (an instance of `int`) as arguments, but nothing I define myself.

The following illustrates what I want in C++ passing an object as an argument:

```
class Bar {
    // ...
};

class Foo{
        void ffoo(Bar arg){
        // ...
    }
};
```

The following illustrates the same in cython, but is incorrect:

```
cdef class Bar:
    # ...

cdef class Foo:
    cdef void ffoo(self, Bar arg):
        # ...
```

The following illustrates what I want in C++ passing an object as an argument:

```
class Base {
    // ...
};

class Derived : public Base {
    // ...
};

class Foo{
        void ffoo(Base* arg){
        // ...
        std::vector<Base*> internal_vec;
    }
};
```

I tried to do this in my attempts at the end of the question.

Basically, I need to pass instances of class `Bar` as arguments. (see first attempt below)

I also want to store a vector of pointers to a base type.

Is this possible?

I’ve checked the Cython documentation, blogs, and similar questions on StackOverflow, but I can’t seem to get this very basic feature to work.

Below are my attempts.

### First Attempt (inherit from object, pass object as argument type)

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

pkg_name = 'soquestion'

compile_args = []
bar = Extension(
        name=pkg_name + '.bar',
        sources=[
            pkg_name + '/bar.pyx',
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=compile_args,
    )

foo = Extension(
        name=pkg_name + '.foo',
        sources=[
            pkg_name + '/foo.pyx',
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=compile_args,
    )

setup(
    name=pkg_name,
    ext_modules=cythonize(bar,
                            annotate=True,
                            build_dir='build') \
                            + cythonize(foo,
                            annotate=True,
                            build_dir='build'),# \
    packages=[
        pkg_name
    ],
)
```

**bar.pxd**

```
cdef class Bar(object):
    cdef int i
```

**bar.pyx**

```
cdef class Bar(object):
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

From [Language
Basics](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html?highlight=%22except%20%20%22#python-objects-as-parameters-and-return-values),

> The name object can also be used to explicitly declare something as a
>   Python object.

**foo.pxd**

```
from soquestion.bar cimport Bar

cdef class Foo(object):
    cpdef void ffoo(self, object arg)
```

**foo.pyx**

```
from soquestion.bar cimport Bar

cdef class Foo(object):
    cpdef void ffoo(self, object arg):
        # obviously, cython would have to know that arg has member i
        arg.i = 3
        print(arg.i)
```

**Output**

```
>>> from soquestion.bar import Bar
>>> from soquestion.foo import Foo
>>> a = Bar
>>> b = Foo
>>> b.ffoo(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'ffoo' requires a 'soquestion.foo.Foo' object but received a 'type'
```

### Second Attempt (store pointer to base type)

(I got a little bit lazy, but the derived class should still be able to hold a vector of pointers to the base type.)

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

pkg_name = 'soquestion'

compile_args = []
bar = Extension(
        name=pkg_name + '.bar',
        sources=[
            pkg_name + '/bar.pyx',
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=compile_args,
    )

foo = Extension(
        name=pkg_name + '.foo',
        sources=[
            pkg_name + '/foo.pyx',
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=compile_args,
    )

derived = Extension(
        name=pkg_name + '.derived',
        sources=[
            pkg_name + '/derived.pyx',
        ],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=compile_args,
    )


setup(
    name=pkg_name,
    ext_modules=cythonize(bar,
                            annotate=True,
                            build_dir='build') \
                            + cythonize(foo,
                            annotate=True,
                            build_dir='build'), \
                            + cythonize(derived,
                            annotate=True,
                            build_dir='build') \

    packages=[
        pkg_name
    ],
)
```

**bar.pxd**

```
cdef class Bar(object):
    cdef int i
```

**bar.pyx**

```
cdef class Bar(object):
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

**foo.pxd**

```
cdef class Foo(object):
    cpdef void ffoo(self, object arg)
```

**foo.pyx**

```
cdef class Foo(object):
    cpdef void ffoo(self, object arg):
        # obviously, cython would have to know that arg has member i
        arg.i = 3
        print(arg.i)
```

**derived.pxd**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from soquestion.bar cimport Bar

cdef class Derived(Bar):
    cdef vector[Bar*] vec
    cdef void store_ptr(self, Bar* b)
```

**derived.pyx**

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from soquestion.bar cimport Bar

cdef class Derived(Bar):
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    cdef void store_ptr(self, Bar* b):
        self.vec.push_back(b)
```

**Output**

On every line where `Bar *` appears, I get

```
soquestion/derived.pxd:5:20: Pointer base type cannot be a Python object
```

Comment: You say you have tried something. If you add your attempt as [mcve] with exact error message that would clarify what your problem is. Right now it doesn’t make a lot of sense: cdef classes-objects are python objects, so I doubt cython tells you it cannot concert them to python objects.

Comment: I clarified the question. This only happens when I try to store pointers to Cython objects.

Comment: As you can see in @DavidW's answer there is no `*` in the signature with `Bar`.  Python-objects (also cdef-classes) aren't pointers.

Comment: Putting python objects in stl-containers isn't a simple task because of the reference counting, see for example this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696844/5769463

Comment: It looks like the Naive Solution in your answer is the closest to what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should work basically how you've written it. Python (and hence Cython) requires an explicit `self` argument, unlike C++ which has an implicit `this` argument.

```
cdef class Foo: 
    cdef void ffoo(self, Bar arg):
       pass
```

You don't need to type `self` since Cython can work it out.

---

In terms of your examples: there is no need to inherit from `object` - `cdef class`es are automatically Python objects anyway. I don't think this does any harm, but it may have some unexpected consequences.

In your first example it fails because you are passing the type objects rather than a Python instance. *This is a basic error with your understanding of Python and has nothing to do with Cython*. Call the type object to create an instance:

```
>>> a = Bar()
>>> b = Foo()
>>> b.ffoo(a)
```

Your second example is trying to use C++ containers to store a collection of `cdef class` instances. This is possible but its considerably more complicated than you think. Among other things you need to be very careful to do reference counting. `Bar*` is not something that Cython recognises if `Bar` is a `cdef class`. Just use a Python list instead.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add `self` in the question. I’ve updated it now.

Comment: It'd be good to know what isn't working. I believe this syntax should work fine.

Comment: I updated my code to show exactly what isn’t working.

Comment: Isn’t a Python list going to be slower than using an array or vector of pointers? I don’t need lists that store pointers to objects that don’t share a base class in my project. I’m trying to remove any overhead that a list would introduce. At any rate, I’d like to know how to use pointers to my own objects in Cython.

Comment: I was getting object not callable or something earlier, but I didn’t commit it, so I don’t know why that happened. This works now. I’m working on the reference counting now since I’ll have to use that pretty often in my project.

Comment: A Python list is actually surprisingly good. In C the Python list is implemented as an array of `PyObject*` so ends up being pretty close to what you're planning to dob anyway.