# using cpp maps with array values in cython

Tags: python, c, cython

I am trying to build a map with ints as keys and lists of integers as values. I've written the following test.pyx file:

```
from libcpp.map cimport map as cmap
import array
from libcpp.pair cimport pair as cpair
from cpython cimport array

cdef cmap[int, int[:]] dict_to_cmap(dict the_dict):
    cdef int map_key
    cdef int[:] map_val
    cdef cpair[int, int[:]] map_element
    cdef cmap[int, int[:]] my_map
    for key,val in the_dict.items():
        map_key = key
        map_val = array.array('i', val)
        map_element = (map_key, map_val)
        my_map.insert(map_element)
    print("values are:")
    print(my_map[1], my_map[1][0])
    print(my_map[2], my_map[2][0])
    return my_map

def test():
    the_dict = {1:[1], 2:[1]}
    dict_to_cmap(the_dict)
```

When I compile this code with:
`python test_setup.py build_ext --inplace`
And run it with:
`python -c "import test; test.test()"`

The result is:

```
values are:
(<MemoryView of 'NoneType' at 0x7f018b837be0>, -1954556344)
(<MemoryView of 'NoneType' at 0x7f018b837d88>, 1)
```

As you can see one of the results is corrupted. What am I doing wrong? It seems that this has something to do with `int[:]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Void pointer pointing to the same address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53695695/void-pointer-pointing-to-the-same-address)

Comment: I do not think so but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cython memoryview doesn't own the data, it's just a view on memory. You should not pass a view of `array`to a C++ map, because the `array` object will finally be garbage collected by Python. That's why you got the result of viewing on None. So who should own the data and manage the reference counts? — C++

Here is a working one:

```
from libcpp.map cimport map as cmap
from libcpp.pair cimport pair as cpair
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef cmap[int, vector[int]] dict_to_cmap(dict the_dict):
    cdef int map_key
    cdef vector[int] map_val
    cdef cpair[int, vector[int]] map_element
    cdef cmap[int, vector[int]] my_map
    for key,val in the_dict.items():
        map_key = key
        map_val = val  # list values will be copied to C++ vector
        map_element = (map_key, map_val)
        my_map.insert(map_element)
    return my_map

def test():
    the_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[4, 5, 6]}
    print(dict_to_cmap(the_dict))  # Cython will automatically convert the C++ map to a Python dict
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer!